# How can i search more than one Username by UserSearchManager in openfire using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am creating chat app using **smack** library and **openfire server XMPP protocol**. First i searched a username by UserSearchManager and i got jid. so it is working good.

But now i have a lot of username and i want to search all username together by Usersearchmanager.
I can do it by calling one by one so that it hit to server again and again.
so please suggest me that how can i search username together at one time search hit.

this is my code which is using search a single username.

```
 UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);
             Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search." + connection.getServiceName());

             Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
             answerForm.setAnswer("search", "rahul rawat");
             answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);

             ReportedData data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm, "search." + connection.getServiceName());

             System.out.println("\nThe jids from our each of our hits:");

             Iterator<Row> rows = data.getRows();
             while (rows.hasNext()) 
             {
                Row row = rows.next();

                Iterator<String> jids = row.getValues("jid");
                while (jids.hasNext()) {
                   System.out.println(jids.next());
                }
             }
```

Comment: what is the need for that? Search works for keywords. So if you send `rahul` it will return you all the usernames who have `rahul` in them

Comment: Sunil :-  I created username as phone number so that there is unique username and i have a number of contact in my phone contact so i want to match with server username for that which contact is on server. so it will hit one by one and i want work as array so all my phone contact will be match with server contact at one time hit.

Comment: The whole point of XMPP is to utilise a roster so there would not be a very regular use case for searching on usernames that aren't already your buddies.

The roster works on request and confirmation and the results are stored in openfire and sent on request by the client....

Comment: yes james. But roster can work only if user has their buddy so user has roster but i want to matching with all the username of openfire server.